# how keep visible ToolTip while mouse is over it?

Tags: java, user-interface, tooltip, visibility, jtooltip

Is there any way to keep a `JToolTip` visible while mouse is over the component who owns it, or the tooltip itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you try using setToolTipText() method. Here btnNext is JButton.

```
btnNext.setToolTipText("Next");
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, what I'm really asking is: once the tooltip is visible, if I move the mouse out of the component who "owns" the tooltip after a brief time the tooltip disappears, what I want is to keep visible the tooltip as long as the mouse is over the component (in your code sample btnNext), or the tooltip itself, how can I do that?

Comment: I updated the answer. Now you can try. This will solve your problem of vaninishing tooptip after brief moment of time.

Comment: I'm aware of the use of setDismissDelay, the thing is that I don't want a specific period of time, I want a undetermined period of time, and when the user moves the mouse out then hide the tooltip

Comment: +1 for @Laf. Yes it suppose to keep it forever. But I dont want to do this experiment and stare at tooltip while doing nothing. Are you sure Ordiel it wont keep the tooltip forever. if not then its a time to hack that.

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I realized it was the same as yours ;) The test should be quick: move mouse cursor over component, validate that the tooltip appears and doesn't hide after say 10 seconds, move cursor out of component, validate the tooltip gets hidden. I don't think you have to wait forever to make sure that it does show forever ;)

Comment: Cool - i think this is the most advised approach; same thing also stated at this link: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0528.html.

Comment: well, I'll try to do that tomorrow, time to go home for now, thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: @Ordiel After doing lots of research I found thread to your problem. [Look this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822819/dynamically-update-tooltip-currently-displayed/12823177#12823177). I am sure it will help to solve your problem.