# setDissmissDelay() method in ToolTipManager not setting its value

Tags: java, swing, timer, awt

I want to set `setDissmissDelay()` method multiple times, but I could not set it for a specific value again and again. I also tried to use an infinite loop, and tried to override (ToolTipManager Constructor is on default modifier).

I know for sure the code is working properly as I can see it's printing the `e.getsource()` in console. I was trying to solve this issue asked by someone ([This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750104/how-keep-visible-tooltip-while-mouse-is-over-it/13750186#13750186)) and while solving that I became stumped at this point. What is the reason behind that? And if I can set the value how can it be? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Here is my code snippet:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Hello {
    static JButton button;

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button = new JButton("Hello World");
        button.setToolTipText("Its a tool tip Experiment!");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                if (e.getSource() == button) {
                    ActionListener tt = new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(
                                    1000);
                            System.out.println(e.getSource());
                        }
                    };
                    new Timer(100, tt).start();
                }
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please guide me through this.

Comment: What's the point of calling setDismissDelay in a Swing Timer? Just set it once and for all

Comment: Well if you check the link I gave in my question, you will come to know that tooltip will go off after some time. So I am calling setDissMissDelay with time to call it repeatedly, However timer is working but setDissMissDelay is not updating value. Why not its updating?

Comment: @smit: _", you will come to know that tooltip will go off after some time"_ No kidding? And I will also learn that the sky is blue? I still don't understand why you would want to set the dismiss delay over and over? What is your objective of performing that? prevent the tooltip from disappearing?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I just want to know the answer that why its not setting that value over and over? My objective to keep it forever, but thats already been asked question.

Comment: @kleopatra What do you mean by "what do you expect?" I just want reason behind this.

Comment: just what I asked - as your code simply doesn't make sense to me: still don't understand what you are _really_ after ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra I am trying to overwrite setDissMissDelay values so that it could keep tooltip forever. BUt to my surprise I could not overwrite this value. so I just want nice explanation why its not overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setDismissDelay()` is a global setting to indicate how long should a Tooltip remain on the display before it is removed. It does not reset the time until when the current tooltip is removed. As suggested in your linked question setting the dismiss delay, once and for all, to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` should do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain more about "Global Setting"? And there is no way to reset its value until tooltip has been removed?

Comment: @smit The ToolTipManager is a static instance that handles all default tooltips across the JVM. It decides when to show a tooltip and when to hide them according to MouseEvent's. I don't really understand why you can't set the dismiss delay to a very high value so that it gets never removed, as long as the mouse hovers your component. You will probably understand what is going on by opening the source code of `ToolTipManager`.

Comment: I gave the same answer to set it to max integer value and I already check ToolTipManager class. After checking I come to know that after 2^31-1 milliseconds, it will disappear. So I come to create this code. However I don't see anything useful to overwrite setDissMissDelay without creating your own setDissMissDelay method to achieve this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @smit 2^31-1 milliseconds is about 24 days? You really stay with your mouse that long over the same component? If you really want, you can always send a fake MouseEvent on the ToolTipManager: take a look at what is done in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822819/dynamically-update-tooltip-currently-displayed/12823177#12823177).

Comment: No definitely I dont want to do that. Thats why I put in my example delay for 1000 miliseconds for testing purpose.

Comment: @smit - What you seem to be missing is that `setDismissDelay()` will have *no effect on the current tooltip that is being displayed*. When the tooltip appears, internally the countdown is started and nothing is going to stop it. The tooltip will stay visible until you either move off the button, or that amount of time runs out. Once the tooltip disappears it's not coming back unless you move your mouse off the button and back onto it and a new countdown is started, once again, using whatever value has been set via `setDismissDelay()`. In summary: You can't alter/reset a countdown in progress.

Comment: @BrianRoach _"nothing is going to stop it_" Why not? What is so special about it? and what is hack I could use?