# Tooltip-like message following cursor arrow

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tooltip

How can I obtain a small message (with constant background, like a tooltip) that follows the arrow cursor with Swing and Java 7? I mean, a tooltip-like message not dependent on which component the cursor is currently on, but a text which always follow the cursor movement & be "fixed" with it.

Thanks.

Comment: how can it be "..does not depend on where is the cursor and that is "fixed" to the cursor arrow" . You are contradicting yourself

Comment: Maybe, he meant to say - not dependent on which component the cursor is currently on, but a text which always follow the cursor movement & be with it.

Comment: To @OliverWatkins: I exactly meant what R Kaja Mohideen wrote. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- AFAIK this could be done, possible by using [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)
- maybe there are another notifiers, code must be dealyed on some period, carefully with `E`(vent)`D`(ispath)`T`(hread)
- is required to use [SwingUtilities.convertXxx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertMouseEvent%28java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.event.MouseEvent,%20java.awt.Component%29) for `ToolTip` added to `JPanel`, `JPanel` which contains, there are added another `JComponents`
- for example

[image: .] [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolTip;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

public class DynamicToolTipTest {

    private JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicToolTipTest");

    public DynamicToolTipTest() {
        ToolTipManager ttm = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
        ttm.setInitialDelay(200);
        ttm.setDismissDelay(10000);
        panel.setToolTipText("Text 1");
        final Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            private int id = 1;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ++id;
                panel.setToolTipText("Text " + id);
            }
        });
        timer.start();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DynamicToolTipTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private static final class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            final JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            final PropertyChangeListener updater = new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                    if (e.getNewValue() != null) {
                        tip.setTipText((String) e.getNewValue());
                        tip.repaint();
                    }
                }
            };
            tip.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
                @Override
                public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
                    //start listening for tip text changes only after the tip 
                    //is displayed, i.e. the tip is added to the component hierarchy
                    MyPanel.this.addPropertyChangeListener(TOOL_TIP_TEXT_KEY, updater);
                }

                @Override
                public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
                    //stop listening for tip text changes once the tip is no longer 
                    //displayed, i.e. the tip is removed from the component hierarchy
                    MyPanel.this.removePropertyChangeListener(TOOL_TIP_TEXT_KEY, updater);
                }

                @Override
                public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
                }
            });
            return tip;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [see code by using SwingUtilities.convertXxx posted by @Guillaume Polet (on one second period)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12823177/714968)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code works pretty good, but it does not fit my needs (needs that I described terribly, I must say...). The problem here is that I want that the message remain visible even if the cursor hover other `JComponent`s that have set a specific tooltip. I'll edit answer's title.

Comment: this is mentioned, by using SwingUtilities.convertXxx from JComponent to the parent (e.g. JPanel)

Comment: Ok, I'll give an eye as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the best solution. But it semms odd to me that there is no "standard" way of doing it! BTW, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `setToolTipText(String)` to your component.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?